# making a sudoku table in javascript with DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So Im trying to generate a sudoku board using javascript and html. Its for a school project using javascript DOM. The idea is to use loops and DOM.

I need it to be a 3x3 of 3x3s. so for instance the end html make look like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box1"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box2"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
        <td class="box3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box4"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box5"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
        <td class="box6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box7"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box8"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
        <td class="box9"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the code I have come up with but it doesn't work the way I intented it to. please check the jsfiddle to see. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

```
function myFunction(){

    for(x=1;x<4;x++){

        var tabley = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tabley.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<tr>');

        for(i=1;i<4;i++){

            tabley.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<td class="box" id="' + i + '">' + i + '</td>');

        }

        var tabley = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tabley.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','</tr>');
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oodma31u/1/

also, i'm not worried about the numbering for now. I can work that out on my own.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: no need to redeclare tabley three times...

Comment: fair point jonas

Answer (score 2):

Dont do it like this. Do the data in JS, just display it using html.For example:

```
var board=[
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
];
```

Now you can access a certain Position like this:

```
board[y][x]=value;
//e. g.
board[0][0]=2;
```

To display it, do:

```
document.body.innerHTML="<table><tr>"+board.map(row=>"<td>"+row.join("</td><td>")+"</td>").join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr></table>";
```

http://jsbin.com/yizoquqoni/edit?output

Comment: hey jonas, thank you for taking time to help me. Im having trouble understanding this a bit. Would it be at all possible for you put it up on js fiddle? thanks buddy. really appreciate your help

Comment: @Dan shure. added

Comment: Thanks for posting but I'm afraid I wasn't clear in my question at all (very sorry about that). I need to be able to make a sudoku board where I give each 3x3 a class. so i need a 3x3 of 3x3s. Please tell me if thats confusing and I will try to word it better lol

Comment: @Dan why?? for checking+ calculating results its not neccessary.

Comment: its more for styling sake. my teacher is a pain and wants this done in a specific way. I agree that its stupid to do it this way. no to mention is would be far easier in jQuery lol. Ive edited my origional question to make it clearer what im after.